# Why is variable not redefined with each iteration of for loop batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have this issue where I want to re-define a variable with each iteration of a for loop. I cannot figure out why this is not working. I have tried messing with `enabledelayedexpansion` but have not had success.

```
echo off
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=::/ " %%A in ("%DATE% %TIME%") do set capture_time=%%D-%%B-%%C_%%E%%F%%G
for /l %%a in (1,1,3) do (
    echo %capture_time%
    timeout 3 /nobreak
    for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=::/ " %%A in ("%DATE% %TIME%") do set capture_time=%%D-%%B-%%C_%%E%%F%%G
)
```

My desired output would be something like this:

```
2015-08-27_132506.50
2015-08-27_132509.50
2015-08-27_132512.50
```

Where each time the loop is run, the `capture_time` is updated.

Comment: You fell into the [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905/5047996) trap! The variable _is_ set but it is expanded earlier so you don't see the updated value... In [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30234238/5047996) for instance, there is exactly the same problem...

Comment: I applied the answer from your first link but it still didn't work. Is it different because I am re-defining the variable "from scratch" each iteration?

Comment: The delayed expansion must also be applied to `!DATE!` and `!TIME!`...

Comment: Would you like to make this an official answer?

Comment: See @Mofi's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32264304/5047996)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every environment variable within a block defined with `(` and `)` and referenced with `%Variable Name%` is expanded already by command processor on parsing the block. This can be seen on running a batch file from within a command prompt window with using `echo on` or having `@echo off` removed or commented out with `rem`.

The solution is using delayed expansion as demonstrated below.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=::/ " %%A in ("%DATE% %TIME%") do set "capture_time=%%D-%%B-%%C_%%E%%F%%G"
for /l %%a in (1,1,3) do (
    echo !capture_time!
    timeout 3 /nobreak
    for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=::/ " %%A in ("!DATE! !TIME!") do set "capture_time=%%D-%%B-%%C_%%E%%F%%G"
)
endlocal
```

For more details on delayed expansion open a command prompt window, execute there `set /?` and read all help pages output into the command prompt window carefully. Delayed expansion is explained in help on an example.

Why it is always better to use `set "variable=value"` instead of `set variable=value` is explained for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564).