# Windows Batch Echoing Two Variables On One Line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I am trying to make a batch file tool at my work to assist with troubleshooting.  I am trying to print two variables on one line, but everything I have tried does not work.  How can I accomplish echoing and calling two variables to one line?  Here is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
title Get Remote Processes
echo Get Remote Processes
set /p computerName="Enter workstation ID or IP address: "
echo %computerName%
echo Getting remote processes...
echo.
pslist \\%computerName%
echo.
set /p answer1="Would you like to kill a process (Y or N)? "
echo %answer1%
IF /i %answer1%==N (
    echo.
    cmd /k
) ELSE (
    set /p processName="Enter process name or ID: "
    echo %processName% %computerName%
    pskill \\%computerName% %processName%
)
echo.
cmd /k
```

> Expected outcome is ComputerName ProcessName.  Current outcome is only ComputerName.  I found that processName is not being stored for some reason even after the user inputs the value.

Comment: you know that you have to enter something after the "Enter process name or ID: " prompt? If you do it works perfectly!

Comment: What is the value of %processName% that you are entering? The way you have it written is the correct way to echo two variables next to each other. There's no reason for processName to not be set unless you started it with a `|` or a `&` or something.

Comment: processName is anything entered by the user, for example, iexplore, svchost, etc.

Comment: You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) since you are setting _and_ reading the same environment variable in the same parenthesised block of code, namely the `if` block...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [variable not getting update inside if condition in batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234238/variable-not-getting-update-inside-if-condition-in-batch-script)

Answer (score 0):

As aschipfl already stated in the comments, you have to use Delayed Expansion.
Add `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to the beginning of your script and wherever you use a variable that you set in the same set of brackets, you have to change the `%` at the front and back of your variable to `!` .

You can test it yourself with this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set foo=bar
If ""=="" (
set foo=foobar
echo."No Expansion" %foo%
echo."Expanded    " !foo!
)
Pause
```

I had the problem with a For-Loop as well and with the Delayed Expansion all works fine now. You should try that out...

Greetings

geisterfurz007